# extract the first word from a string - regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
str1 = "cat-one,cat2,cat-3";
OR
str1 = "catone,cat-2,cat3";
OR
str1 = "catone";
OR
str1 = "cat-one";
```

The point here is words may/may not have "-"s in it

Using regex:
How could I extract the 1st word?

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
L

Comment: This matches all characters up to the first comma: ^[^,]+

Comment: This is what I tried (and works!) and hope that's right:

alert ( str.replace (/^([^,]+)(.*)?/, "$1") );

Comment: If that's really all you want to do, this would work just as well: alert(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(',')))

Comment: `(.*)?` in your regex is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's pretty easy, just include allowed characters in brackets:

`^([\w\-]+)`

Comment: He said extract, so I assumed it needed the parentheses.

Comment: I'm new here, so I may be missing something, but I copied "^([\w-])+" from your (temporary?) answer to test it.

Comment: @Ekkehard Apologies; I caught a typo in my answer seconds after I posted it, and you must have seen it before I corrected it.

Comment: Can you explain what does the () does and the first ^?

Comment: `^([^\w])*([\w\-]+)` also considers possible preceeding spaces or non-word characters

Answer (score 1):

An approach not using a regex: assuming the first word is delimited always by a comma "," you can do this:

```
var str1 = "cat-one";
var i = str1.indexOf(",");
var firstTerm = i == -1 ? str1 : str1.substring(0, i);
```

**Edit:**  Assumed this was a javascript question, for some reason.

Comment: regex is actually easier this time, I think. :) He also didn't say he was using javascript.

Comment: @Seth: yeah, you are right. Dunno why I thought was js. Perhaps because no type definition?

Answer (score 1):

If someone, one day would like to do it in Swift here you go with an extension :

```
extension String {

    func firstWord() -> String? {
        var error : NSError?
        let internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!
        let matches = internalExpression.matchesInString(self, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, countElements(self)))
        if (matches.count > 0) {
            let range = (matches[0] as NSTextCheckingResult).range
            return (self as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

To use it just write:

```
myString.firstWord()
```

Comment: In this case Richard H's answer of avoiding the direct regular expression is probably best and just use this Swift expression;

str.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[0]

Comment: Indeed you are right. But if you are looking for something for generic then I would avoid using hard-coded "," solutions. Maybe next time the separator could be "_", "-", ".", etc.