# read each line of a text up to the first space into a cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io

I have a multi line text file that in each line has 3 words separated by some spaces. I want to write the first word of each line into a nX1 cell array, so that:

```
cell{1}{1}=line1_1stword

cell{1}{2}=line2_1stword
.
.
.
```

How can I do that? I know that the following command reads each line into a line of the cell, but I want just the first word.

```
fid = fopen(`myFile.ext`)
allData = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
fid = fopen('myFile.ext')
allData = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n')

%%// Read in the first word from each row of data
outcellarray = regexp(allData{:},'^([\w\-]+)','match')

%%// Store all the first words into a single cell array of strings
outcellarray = vertcat(outcellarray{:})
```

Inspired by [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041474/3293881).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21710-string-toolkits/content/strings/strsplit.m"Download the file from MatlabCentral here") function.

```
cell=strsplit(text,' ')
```