# extract first two word from an string exclude comma using regex in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
select regexp_matches('Hi, I am Harry Potter', '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\W+\w+');
select regexp_matches('Hi, I am Harry Potter', '\w+\W+\w+');
```

Both way returns `{Hi, I}`
But expect `{Hi I}`.
Related Question: extract first word in an String: [extract the first word from a string - regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041453/extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match disjoint (non-adjoining) parts of a string into a single group.

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to capture the first two words into separate groups and then use two backreferences to the group in the replacement pattern to get what you need:

```sql
select regexp_replace('Hi, I am Harry Potter', '^\W*(\w+)\W+(\w+).*', '\1 \2');
```

See the [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2eb0b7c219a7e25002e52ea39aa66f7). The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/3oYDql/1) means

- `^` - start of string
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more word chars
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more word chars
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: I wonder why cannot match {Hi, I} together?

Comment: @JianHe "*You cannot match disjoint (non-adjoining) parts of a string into a single group.*" A matched string is Group 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
select regexp_match(
          'Hi, I am Harry Potter',
          '^([[:alnum:]]+)[^[:alnum:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)'
       );

 regexp_matches 
════════════════
 {Hi,I}
(1 row)
```

The pattern matches the first sequence of alphanumerical characters, then a sequence of non-alphanumerical characters and another sequence of alphanumerical characters. The result is an array with the first and third expression, which are parenthesized in the pattern.